# Replacing an old two-pole contactor in A/C

Tags: hvac

I have a very old Career Bryant heat pump (38YH060300) with burnt contactor. I called an online A/C parts store asking if they have a replacement in stock, but they said it's a very specific contactor model (hn52td024 & hn52kd024) and they don't have it in stock. Some other websites sell it for $100.
Then I called a local store and they simply said that practically any replacement contactor will be fine.
Could someone please confirm this? Can I just buy any 24V / 40A contactor as replacement?
Thank you!

Comment: Any contactor with the same specs should work, but the connections/mounting probably different enough to require work to make fit/connect.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, we'd have to see how it's wired.  If it has six spade terminals, four for 240VAC and two for 24V thermostat, then yeah, it's any old A/C contactor. Last time I bought one it was $13.  You are free to use a "specific purpose" contactor (UR-Recognized) made for HVAC motor control, you don't need a "general purpose" (UL Listed) type.

Comment: Thank you for the above responses. I've replaced capacitors before, but it's my first time looking at a contactor, so I'm a newbie with this. I'll just go with a generic one then.

Comment: Take a pic, so we can help looking for one. I found one for $55 but not sure

Comment: https://upstatehvac.com/shop/factory-authorized-parts-hn52td024-contactor-2-pole-40fla-24v-50-60hz/

Comment: Yeah -- any "definite purpose" contactor with suitable ratings, terminations, and mountings will do here